# Click on FontAwesome icon cause Full Postback in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, font-awesome, updatepanel

I have some pages in Asp.Net webforms with some update panel (with `UpdateMode="Conditional"`) and inside it an asp:LinkButton with inside a fontawesome icon like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success  btn-responsive">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user-circle"></span> Foo
</asp:LinkButton>
```

When i click precisely on the icon the page goes full postback and and non partial postback as I expect

Searching i understand that the problem might be event propagation, so i create a script like that:

```
$('.fa').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (!(this.parentNode === null)) {
        this.parentNode.click();
    }
});
```

This works for html button with runat="server" tag, but not working with asp:linkbutton, also i have thousand of link button and i can't override them all.
Any suggestion?

Best regards

UPDATE:

Here is the page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Iscr.aspx.vb" Inherits="Iscr" %>
```

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelIscr" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

            prm.add_endRequest(function () {
                load();
                loadScript();
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                loadScript();
            });

            function loadScript() {

            }

        </script>

    ...form....

        <div class="floatingButtonBar">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success  btn-responsive">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user-circle"></span> Foo
        </asp:LinkButton>
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You don't need to take care of event propagation. Add `OnClientClick`  for LinkButton  with `return false()`.

Comment: @Sagar this will not work because it will not launch the server event in any case with `OnClientClick="return false;"` on the linkbutton

Comment: Can you please show the code of script manager?

Comment: @Sagar I edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your update panel attribute called `UpdateMode` to `Conditional`

Example :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
```

---

Update:

Also make sure that page directive  `ClientIDMode` is `AutoID`
Example :

```
<%@ Page Title="" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Language="C#"%>
```

---

Update :

Seems that  `ClientIDMode="Static"` is not working with update panel , please check the fix : 
[Possible solution to UpdatePanel and ClientIDMode="Static"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744513/possible-solution-to-updatepanel-and-clientidmode-static)

Comment: Take a look on updated answer and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Is this mandatory to have `ClientIDMode="AutoID"` ? I set the whole project to have  `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: This could cause the issue, please try to remove ClientIDMode="Static" if its working you need to find better solution.
I will help more if you post you code.

Comment: with ClientIDMode="AutoID" it works... damn. I edited the main post with the whole page, can you help me? I can't edit the whole project with AutoID

Comment: seems that ClientIDMode="Static" not working with update panel. Take a look on this fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744513/possible-solution-to-updatepanel-and-clientidmode-static

Comment: It Works! thanks a lot! please update the answer so i check as positive

Comment: Happy to help you.

Comment: i found an issue, with UpdateMode="Conditional" and the fix script its not update my hiddenfield anymore